# XML Serialization of Object with other object inside .net

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio, serialization

I'm trying to XML-serialize a class the properties of which I use to format a document.
Basically, it is a class for the document's header and another class for its rows.

Class diagram:

[image: classdiagram]

In this class diagram, the class I want to serialize is `ExcelPrintCorte` that inherits its methods from `ExcelCabec` and has a private member `ExcelPrintDocumento` (and a public method to get it).

My purpose is to XML-serialize `ExcelPrintCorte` and save the inherited properties' values and also the properties' values of `ExcelPrintDocumento`. I followed many guides to XML-serialize an object but it saves nothing but:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ExcelPrintCorte xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Or is what I'm trying to do not possible with XML serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to tell without code, but:

- the properties (or less commonly, fields) you want to serialize must be *public*
- the properties (blah) must be *mutable*, i.e. not `get`-only or `readonly`
- anything marked `[XmlIgnore]` is ignored, and a few other rules like `[DefaultValue]`, `ShouldSerialize{foo}` etc are observed

Those are the rules that would stop *anything* showing; other errors that would cause *exceptions* (check the inner-exceptions etc):

- not public (including any containing types)
- no public parameterless constructor (including: must be concrete)
- unexpected sub-types (i.e. not previously advertised with `[XmlInclude]`)
- some member-types; `object`, dictionaries, lists without an obvious `Add`, etc

Comment: Now i notice my mistake is (at least one). Most of the properties are readonly, i didn't want to be possible to edit them in runtime, but now that you said it, it's really stupid since i need to deserialize it to a class. I will check it now and post the correction's results. Thanks.

PS: One question, when you said properties(blah), you are not fan of that designation? Which do you use?

Comment: @jaimetotal - absolutely properties are the way to expose data; the "blah" was just to avoid repetition. public fields are *bad*.